# 2-components machine

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Can you help me just making me understand the point?

*I have a 2-components machine. Both components have independent lifetimes, distributed as exponential r.v. with expected value $\mu$ = 5. To make a job they simultaneously work and, if components break, they will be fixed simultaneously (there are moments in which just a component is working).*

Considering X(t) the number of functioning componet at time t (t>0), compute:

lim (t--> ∞) of P[X(t+s) = 1] for every s in [0,5]

I don't understand why it should be different from computing the limit of P[X(t) = 1], which is a previous point.

Can you help me understanding this?

Comment: Don't we have to know how long it takes to fix a component?

Comment: @saulspatz components are fixed simultaneously and immediatly, we can ignore fixing time